# Custom view for events

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I am using fullcalendar to display events using list view. Fullcalendar uses a table to render the list of events. I am using custom properties in addiction to title, start and end period therefore the event table is not very readable on mobile devices. I would prefer to use other HTML elements so that, together with flexbox, I can dispose event properties as needed.
In fullcalendar v5, it is suggested to use a custom view which fullfil my goals (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-js-demo) but I don't know how to customise the example so that I can use week and month filters in the header instead of current, prev and next day button. Any suggestions?
This is the code I am using so far

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        const { sliceEvents, createPlugin, Calendar } = FullCalendar

        const CustomViewConfig = {

            classNames: ['custom-view'],

            content: function(props) {
                let segs = sliceEvents(props, true); // allDay=true
                let html =
                    '<div class="view-title">' +
                    props.dateProfile.currentRange.start.toUTCString() +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div class="view-events">' +
                    segs.length + ' events:' +
                    '<ul>' +
                    segs.map(function(seg) {
                        return seg.def.title + ' (' + seg.range.start.toUTCString() + ')'
                    }).join('') +
                    '</ul>' +
                    '</div>'

                return { html: html }
            }

        }

        const CustomViewPlugin = createPlugin({
            views: {
                custom: CustomViewConfig
            }
        })

        let calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        let calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
            plugins: [CustomViewPlugin],
            initialView: 'custom',
            timeZone: 'UTC',
      
            firstDay: 1,
            events: ... // not using the real array here to make the code shorter for SO
        });

        calendar.render();
    });
```

Comment: I don't know if you really need a completely custom view for this. Have you tried the event render hooks instead? https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-render-hooks

Comment: Yes, I already tried but with the render hooks I can only add nodes inside the table or, using eventDidMount, hide the table and add my own html elements.

Comment: `hide the table and add my own html elements`...isn't that exactly what you're wanting to do?

Comment: I consider that a last resort. It's like hiding dust under the carpet :-)

Comment: Sorry I don't see how that's different to what you're asking for in your question. In the question you say `I would prefer to use other HTML elements...`, and now you say that `hide the table and add my own html elements` isn't what you want. Can you see why I'm confused?

Comment: @ADyson I think that the misunderstanding depends on the fact that I am not English mother tongue. When I wrote "other"  I meant "in place of".  From the docs I understand that it is possible to create a new render function to make the output as I need. It is an option and I know that there are other simpler solutions like hide what I don't need and add what I need. I asked for help on the more complex solution.

Comment: But with the event render hooks you don't have to hide anything. You can simply remove it and replace with your own html elements

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'll give it a try.